# WPF4: How do you set a value in a UserControl from the Main Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf-4.0

This has to be simple, at least it was in good old .Net where it took maybe four lines of code.  I'm working in VS2010, C#, WPF4.

I have a user control with a textbox.  When I click a button in the main window, I want my user control textbox to reflect some text.  Is this possible in WPF4 with less than 500 lines of esoteric code?

The problem is that while I know the textbox is getting the new text as evidenced from breakpoints in the user control code, that text is never being reflected to the main window.  The main window still shows the original text.  It has to be some kind of binding thing, and I really don't think I should have to create templates and resources and all for this simple situation.  It's got to be something simple that I'm forgetting in the forest of WPF4.  Below is what I have.  After clicking the button, the textbox is still blank; it does not say "hello earthlings."

In the user control code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static UserControl1()
    {
        TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

User control xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WTFUserControlLibrary.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<Grid Height="164" Width="220">
    <TextBox Name="txtTest" BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="2" Height="25" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl1, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

(I have no idea what the text binding is supposed to be doing in this case.)

Main window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WTFUserControlLibrary.UserControl1 uc = new WTFUserControlLibrary.UserControl1();
        uc.Text = "hello earthlings";
    }
}
```

and the main window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WTFUserControlLibrary;assembly=WTFUserControlLibrary"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,65,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,94,0,0" Name="userControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" Width="244" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks Earthlings (and also those who designed this mess!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method `button1_Click` you are creating a ***new*** user control. This is not the usercontrol in the window and is never displayed.

Instead, give your usercontrol a name in the XAML:

```
x:Name="uc"
```

Then in the `button1_Click` method you just remove that first line where you create a new usercontrol.

#### update

You want the user control XAML to look more like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WTFUserControlLibrary.UserControl1"
         x:Name="thisControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<Grid Height="164" Width="220">
    <TextBox Name="txtTest" BorderBrush="red" 
             BorderThickness="2" Height="25" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=thisControl, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

I added `x:Name="thisControl"` to the root `UserControl` element, and then referenced this in the binding.

I'll try to explain the binding:

You have this textbox *inside* your user control, but you want to be able to bind the text value to something *outside* the user control. What you've done is set up a dependency property on the user control, and bound that textbox to it, so you are using the binding infrastructure pass values from the top level of the `UserControl` to constituent controls inside it.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
data
    ---> bind UserControl1.Text to data
         ---> bind TextBox.Text to UserControl1.Text
```

Comment: Also, make sure the user control name in the XAML is exactly the same as the name in the TextBox binding.

Comment: I knew I was getting lost in the forest, however, it still isn't working.  If I understand you both, then I should change the name in the main window xaml to:

 <my:UserControl1 x:Name="uc"..., 

remove the new user control in button1_click, and change the user control binding to: 

<TextBox Name="txtTest" Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"...

I'm almost certain this binding is wrong.

Comment: @Larry "no" to the last part. Don't change the name in the binding, because you are defining that *inside the usercontrol*. I'll post an update…

Comment: Wow!  That actually works, and makes sense when explained.  I would probably never have come up with that, or at least taken another two weeks.  And I have the MacDonald tome right in front of me!  I guess I was actually pretty close, but I don't quite get the xaml header code yet.

Jay, thanks ever so much!

Comment: StackOverflow is audacious, now, how do I mark this as resolved and give you credit...?

Comment: @Larry Most of the "noise" in the header are namespace imports. This is just like the `using` directives in a c# file, only much uglier. You can click the gray checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ha, always seems to get uglier in order to get better!